# Writing a file with Raspian Buster

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-buster

I want to write a file in Raspian Buster.
With Raspian Stretch (which relies on Debian 9) it works withount any problems.
The same code does not work on Raspian Buster (Debian 10).

```
File myFile = new File("/media/usb/test.properties");
boolean success = myFile.createNewFile();
```

Even when the directory has the permissions 777 oktal, when trying to write a file always the following exception occurs:

```
java.io.IOException: Das Dateisystem ist nur lesbar (my translation: the file system is readable only)
```

When I first manually create the specified file in the directory, and I check the permissions with Java code, it prints the following results:

```
File f = new File("/media/usb/test.properties");
f.exists(): true
f.canRead(): true
f.canWrite(): false
```

What has changed between Raspian Stretch and Buster?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved according to
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3579

Works fine now!